# Pass through commands into ansi-term

Tags: key-bindings, ansi-term

I'm running into this problem: I have a `tmux` session on a remote machine running in `ansi-term`. I want to be able to, for example, copy and paste stuff in this session, but <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> for example, is intercepted by Emacs and never sent to `tmux`, so, I cannot actually select anything, let alone copy. Is there any way to send any key to `ansi-term`? Ideally, I'd hope to have something like <kbd>C-q C-SPC</kbd> to be interpreted by the terminal as <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>.

I figured there's also `term-send-raw`, but for some reason I cannot make it send `C-SPC` specifically.

---

This is what I've done so far, but I'm not that happy with it:

```lisp
(defun term-passthrough-C-SPC (&optional e)
  (interactive)
  (message "C-SPC was pressed")
  (term-send-raw-string "\C- "))

(defvar term-passthrough-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-SPC") 'term-passthrough-C-SPC)
    map))
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "C-q") term-passthrough-map)
```

Comment: Only one question per post, please. Perhaps your question is *"How can I make `term-send-raw` send `C-SPC`"*? Or *"How can I send a key to ansi-term"*? Or if you have a specific question about your code, then ask it, instead of just saying that you're not happy with it (not happy why/how?).

Comment: @Drew yeah, very helpful. Good job!